# Does '-' if standing for stdin have a specific name?

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe, stdin

In several command line applications, if you pipe stdin into them, you need to provide a `-` character instead of an input file.

Sample:

```
$ foo | bar -
```

Now I wonder: Does this `-` character have an official special name when used in this context, e.g. *dashed stdin operator* or something like this? If so, which one?

*The background of my question is that I want to write a function that detects this character and then treats stdin accordingly instead of parsing the arguments as an array, and I wondered what to call this function.*

Comment: Related: [`man 1 getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) (for if you don't want to parse the ARGV array manually).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the man page does not tell anything about handling stdin, does it?

Comment: No, but you mentioned two different ways of handling parameters -- parsing the arguments as an array, and looking for `-` specifically -- and I thought you might be interested in the more flexible and ready-made functionality that `getopt` provides, not (only) for this specific case, but in general. Thus, a "related" comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX standard doesn't use any special name for this usage of `-` character. It says:

> For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used to mean only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified) or a file named -.

and then

> Where a utility described in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008 as conforming to these guidelines is required to accept, or not to accept, the operand '-' to mean standard input or output, this usage is explained in the OPERANDS section. Otherwise, if such a utility uses operands to represent files, it is implementation-defined whether the operand '-' stands for standard input (or standard output), or for a file named -.

Manual pages don't seem to use any special name either:

> If no files are specified, or if the file "-" is given, *grep* searches standard input.

So it seems you have to invent your own name.